# CSS Doozie: Replacing BG Image on SELECT dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I need to be able to change the background-image property of a SELECT drop-down using JavaScript/CSS. We have been able to accomplish this in Firefox, but it doesn't appear to be supported at all in IE.

From what I've read, IE won't support this. But I'm wondering if there's anything else I could try. Does anyone here have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a fake dropdown list using Javascript, such as [this one](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycombobox.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is re-implement a select in javascript (since custom backgrounds won't work in Webkit either).